# How does Hive choose the number of reducers for a job?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Several places say the default # of reducers in a Hadoop job is 1.  You can use the mapred.reduce.tasks symbol to manually set the number of reducers.

When I run a Hive job (on Amazon EMR, AMI 2.3.3), it has some number of reducers greater than one.  Looking at job settings, something has set mapred.reduce.tasks, I presume Hive.  How does it choose that number?

Note: here are some messages while running a Hive job that should be a clue:

```
...
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 500
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
...
```

Comment: Good question. Specifically, when does hive choose to do `Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time` and when does it choose to do `estimated from input data size`?

Comment: added that in the answer below

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default of 1 maybe for a vanilla Hadoop install. Hive overrides it.

In open source hive (and EMR likely)

```
# reducers = (# bytes of input to mappers)
             / (hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer)
```

[This post](http://karmasphere.com/how-does-analyst-determine-the-number-of-reducer-tasks-per-query) says default hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer is 1G.

You can limit the number of reducers produced by this heuristic using `hive.exec.reducers.max`.

If you know exactly the number of reducers you want,  you can set `mapred.reduce.tasks`, and this will override all heuristics. (By default this is set to -1, indicating Hive should use its heuristics.)

In some cases - say 'select count(1) from T' - Hive will set the number of reducers to 1 , irrespective of the size of input data. These are called 'full aggregates' - and if the only thing that the query does is full aggregates - then the compiler knows that the data from the mappers is going to be reduced to trivial amount and there's no point running multiple reducers.

Comment: Even though full aggregates reduce output data amount from a significant value, More reducers can help to decrease the running time. We are facing an issue with Hive which has 1100+ mappers and only with one reducer. It takes hours to just to finish sort.

Comment: The link is no more valid. Good to post Apache links.