# How to Set Number of Reducers on EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I have a series of Mapper and Reducer tasks that I am running through custom jar steps on aws. I want to run the last reducer task through only one reducer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
SET mapreduce.job.reduces=XX
```

Taken from: [How do you force the number of reducers in a map reduce job to be higher? - Hortonworks](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/28073/how-do-you-force-the-number-of-reducers-in-a-map-r.html)

Or perhaps:

```
SET mapred.reduce.tasks=XX
```

From: [hadoop - How does Hive choose the number of reducers for a job? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203314/how-does-hive-choose-the-number-of-reducers-for-a-job)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by putting job.setNumReduceTasks(1) into the main method of my java file that contains my mapper and reducer.